# Moving the Ubuntu from VM to Disk

Tags: vmware

I am using VM to run Ubuntu 12. Our building has some power problem and sometimes during the weekend things get shutdown without any notification. So, it seems that running Ubuntu on a VM is not a good idea, nothing is stable, and I've started to loose my codes, etc. So, while I have everything I have implemented so far on my Ubuntu(on VM), I wonder if I could install my Ubuntu (with everything saved in it), on a disk and use it as my default Operating System.

Comment: You can create an image of your disk: `sudo dd if=/dev/sda of=/media/my_dev_sdb/disk_sda.img` (If it's your main disk, then it's wise to boot a live session and do it from there instead.)

Comment: Unless vmware is terribly broken, running under a virtual machine isn't any worse as far as sudden loss of power goes ( which is never good ).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May I suggest doing this process instead:

1. Installing ubuntu with a bootable drive onto the computer you want to transfer the files to.
2. Use ubuntu's built in backup function to backup your files and contents to a usb.
3. restore the backup onto the new computer!

Thanks, hope this helps.

Comment: So, both solutions mean that 1)backup what I have, and then 2) Install a fresh Ubuntu 3) and load the backup in the fresh installation. right?

Comment: Yes. It should not take too long tho, much longer than trying to search for another solution!